# SQL sentencia para ubicar si una fecha se encuentra entre otras 2

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Deseo poder encontrar todos los registros con valor 1 en asistencia que se encuentren entre 2 fechas para un usuario:

```
SELECT * FROM asistencia 
WHERE id='124' AND asistencia = '1' AND fecha BETWEEN '2018-07-30' AND '2018-08-12'
```

Y como filtro adicional si en este caso `$fecha_de_ingreso='2018-08-08';` me muestre los 4 registros correspondientes , SI `$fecha_de_ingreso` no se encuentra entre las dos fechas, que no me muestre nada.

Comment: Y cual es el problema? tira algun error?

Comment: Podrias agregarlo dentro de la sentencia where tambien mi estimado.

Comment: la verdad es que no encuentro como identificar si la fecha de ingreso se encuentra dentro de el periodo actual (es decir entre las dos fechas) , la tabla me tiene que mostrar las asistencias dentro del periodo que son en este ejemplo 4

Comment: una buena practica es dejar la labor de logica de utilizacion de datos en el script php, de manera que tu consulta te traiga los datos en bruto y lo valides en el script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola veo que estas filtrando por un **ID** 124, en ese caso solo te traera un registro, para validar si la fecha ingreso esta o no entre el rango de fechas te aconsejo pasar las fechas a un **BIND** y realizarles un **`to_date`** algo asi...

```
SELECT * FROM asistencia 
WHERE asistencia = '1' 
    AND fecha BETWEEN to_date(:fechaInicialRango,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
    AND to_date(:fechFinalRango,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
    AND fecha_ingreso = to_date(:fechIngreso,'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Si no es lo que necesitas dame un poco mas de detalle para ayudarte.

Comment: Si me fuinciono! gracias quedo bien esto es la primera parte de un problema que me a estado molestando y es medio complejo, te copio la explicacion que comparti con Jose Rolando

Comment: Me es muy util gracias lo tratrare de implementar, la verdad este ejercicio esta super cofuso el problema real pertenece a un esquema de nomina. una quincena abarca 15 dias para que la persona se le pague (si no a faltado) pero "el cierre de nomina" habre y cierra el dias 25 del mes pasado y el dia 10 del actual. si Juanito comenzo a trabajar el dia 11 de este mes no se le paga asta la quincena siguiente MAS los 4 dias que le quedaron pendientes de su quincena pasada , quiere decir que al mostrar cuantos dias se le tienen que pagar de el periodo actual son sus 15 dias + 4 y hay que validar

Comment: los dias adicionales se validan al dar de alta al usuario pero en la tabla tien que comprovar si la informacion es correcto de manera logia (y de preferencia en la creacion de usuario salga automatico) y claro esta que esto regreso 0 dias adicionales si la fecha ya paso, por eso mi pregunta va mas por atacar por partes este problema

Comment: Ok me alegra que te funcionara, si puedo ayudarte en algo mas solo avisame, toda mi experiencia en desarrollo ha sido en sistemas de nominas y recursos humanos, tengo conocimiento de la legislación laboral colombiana y algo de la legislación de ecuador. Slds.

Comment: julian gutierrez salgado , la verdad es que pese a que ya tengo un tiempo en esto me e dado cuenta que cuando cambio de trabajo/jefe/protyecto me sirve alguien que me ayude en lo que tomo el ritmo (o simplemente otra cabeza para analizar el problema o evaluar el curso de acion ) y si me gustaria contratar un asesor para esos casos especiales soy de mexico , si puderas mandarme un mensaje para platicarte mas

Comment: Claro claus, contactame y charlamos julianmpn@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta pero la primera sentencia debes escribirla de la siguiente manera para que no te afecte el formato de fecha de la computadora, en caso que la cambies o la ejecutes en otro dispositivo:

```
SELECT * FROM asistencia where id='124' AND asistencia = 1 AND fecha BETWEEN '20180730' AND '20180812'
```

En caso que lo que quieras es que la fecha esté en el rango anterior y que además la fecha de ingreso esté dentro del primer filtro (así fue qe lo entendí), entonces tu sentencias sería así

```
SELECT * FROM asistencia where id='124' AND asistencia=1 AND (fecha BETWEEN '2018-07-30' AND '2018-08-12') AND fecha IN ('20180808')
```

Comment: Me es muy util gracias lo tratrare de implementar, la verdad este ejercicio esta super cofuso el problema  real pertenece a un esquema de nomina. una quincena abarca 15 dias para que la persona se le pague (si no a faltado) pero "el cierre de nomina" habre y cierra el dias 25 del mes pasado y el dia 10 del actual. si Juanito comenzo a trabajar el dia 11 de este mes no se le paga asta la quincena siguiente MAS los 4 dias que le quedaron pendientes de su quincena pasada , quiere decir que al mostrar cuantos dias se le tienen que pagar de el periodo actual son sus 15 dias + 4 . y hay que validar

Comment: los dias adicionales se validan al dar de alta al usuario pero en la tabla tien que comprovar si la informacion es correcto de manera logia (y de preferencia en la creacion de usuario salga automatico) y claro esta que esto regreso 0 dias adicionales si la  fecha ya paso, por eso mi pregunta va mas por atacar por partes este problema